Firebase Analytics - Device Model "not set"
I have an Android app that uses Firebase Analytics. Within the app, there's a feature that opens a webview to another app, also using Firebase Analytics.
I'm curious why the device model is logged as "not set" when opening the app from the webview ?
Sample report device model not set
How to logged device model when open the app from webview ?

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
